# Using SMAPE as a loss function for an LSTM

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm, rnn, loss-function

I am currently working on a time series forecasting problem and am looking into using an LSTM.

My final accuracy metric that I use to determine whether or not the forecast is good or not is defined as follows:

$$\text{SMAPE-3} = \frac{\sum^n_{t=1}|y_t-\hat{y}_t|}{\sum^n_{t=1}\left(y_t+\hat{y}_t\right)},$$

where $y_t$ is the actual value and $\hat{y}_t$ is the forecast value.  So this formula will produce a score between $[0, 1]$.  This score can then be subtracted from 1 to produce a percentage accuracy of the forecast over the specified forecast horizon

$$\text{Accuracy} = 1-\frac{\sum^n_{t=1}|y_t-\hat{y}_t|}{\sum^n_{t=1}\left(y_t+\hat{y}_t\right)}.$$

I am using keras and have seen that I can specify a custom loss function and metric.  As my forecast accuracy will be measured using sMAPE 3 (as defined above) it made sense to me to use this as my loss function.  This is because my networks success will be measured by how well it scores using this.  A score of 0 indicates 100% accuracy and a score of 1 indicates 0% accuracy.

So this raises two questions, can a metric such as smape be used as loss function at all, if so why / why not?  Are the standard loss functions within keras considered better?  Perhaps because they allow quicker convergence?  Does my choice of using SMAPE3 as a loss function have an impact on what kind of optimiser I should use?

I ask because I haven't seen many people using loss functions other than RMSE, MSE and MAE and there must be a reason for this.

Comment: This is a great question. I too have been wondering about using sMAPE.
Was reading a paper on "Modeling approaches for time series forecasting and anomaly detection" (S Du, 2017) . and it mentions using sMAPE as "This metric is more robust towards outliers and it has a unified scale across different time series with different scale." (ibid., 4) But most docs I see are using the standard RMSE, MSE, and MAE metrics. Would love to have this answered.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why not- it's the loss you wish to minimize.

I'm using the following as my loss function and it works well when sMAPE is my metric for prediction accuracy.

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

def smape_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    epsilon = 0.1
    summ = K.maximum(K.abs(y_true) + K.abs(y_pred) + epsilon, 0.5 + epsilon)
    smape = K.abs(y_pred - y_true) / summ * 2.0
    return smape
```